# How to subscribe from ROS Publisher in Arduino?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on arduino <-> ROS and now my problem is that I cannot receive published data in arduino.
I followed rosserial subscribing, publishing tutorials but it seems received message looking at serial monitor is only 0s.

Below is my code used to subscribe in Arduino

ros::NodeHandle nh;

void receiveANGLE( const angle::FSS& msg) {
angle2 = msg.Data;
}

ros::Subscriberangle::FSS sub("FSS", &receiveANGLE);

FSS is the topic I am sending from ROS publisher and it is perfectly sending datas properly. Also, angle is my package name and FSS is also name for my message which is int32.
if i look at angle2 in serial monitor, only
0
0
0
0
0
0
values are seen.

what could be the problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384739/how-to-subscribe-from-ros-publisher-in-arduino?/) by [jang22](https://answers.ros.org/users/80455/jang22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i figured it out...

It was really embarrasing, the thing was i didn't fully understand how the entire communication system is formed and ran.

I first thought just by publishing using ROS and uploading in Arduino, I will be able to get published data in Arduino. However, I had to run " rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=ttyACM0 _baud:=57600"  command for topic from ROS to be connected and subscribed from Arduino. In short, I thought serial connection from ROS and arduino will just be formed by uploading Arduino codes but I had to set up the connection for them.

srry for late upload...

---

Originally posted by [jang22](https://answers.ros.org/users/80455/jang22/) with karma: 26 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-24**:
Can you please! provide the solution, and make your answer tick so that can be helpful to others.

You can click on the edit button over here to update your answer.